# Should I send a (text) message after sending an email?

Tags: applications

Context:

I contacted an employer via phone call looking for work experience. It went to voice mail, and they later texted me asking for me to email my resume through.

It has been 3 days since I sent my email, and no response. I'm aware they are likely busy or this is their way of saying no, but should I have sent a follow up text letting them know I sent it when I did?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't ring up and ask for feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 days later is in the middle ground of too late and too early.

So it would've been wise to send a reply text after you sent in your resume.

Now it's too late for that opportunity, I would not text until you're certain they've not seen the e-mail. However it's too early to be sending a follow up e-mail/text as it's rare that employers reply straight away or at all until they know that they will take you on (or not).

Wait a few more days then send a text mentioning that you sent an e-mail and just wondering if they received it.